# cc3000 WiFi distrupting DS18b20 temp measurements

Tags: arduino-mega, wifi, temperature-sensor, 1-wire

I am trying to post temperature measurements from DS18b20 thermal sensors to an online repository using a cc3000 WiFi shield on an Arduino Mega.  It works great, once.  All the temperatures get read fine. Then I post the data. Then the temperatures all return -127 error values.

If I fix the temperatures to const values, I can send any amount of data over wifi. If I don't send the data over wifi, I can pull temperatures indefinitely.

I can't imagine anyone is set up to test this or has a good way to debug it, so I am open to wild speculation- Any guesses what is going wrong? Any suggestions on how to debug it?

Here is my code:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

#include <Adafruit_CC3000.h>
#include <ccspi.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define temppin 53

#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ   3  // MUST be an interrupt pin!
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT  5  // any pin
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS    10  // any pin
// On an UNO, SCK = 13, MISO = 12, and MOSI = 11
Adafruit_CC3000 cc3000 = Adafruit_CC3000(ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS, ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ, ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT,
                                     SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER); // you can change this clock speed but DI

#define WLAN_SSID       "MyNetwork"        // cannot be longer than 32 characters!
#define WLAN_PASS       "mypassword"
// Security can be WLAN_SEC_UNSEC, WLAN_SEC_WEP, WLAN_SEC_WPA or WLAN_SEC_WPA2
#define WLAN_SECURITY   WLAN_SEC_WPA2
uint32_t dweetioIp = 0;
char c;
unsigned long lastpost = 15000L;

OneWire oneWire(temppin);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);  // Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature.

DeviceAddress TS1 = {0x28, 0xFF, 0xB4, 0x5E, 0x68, 0x14, 0x03, 0x60};  // serial numbers
DeviceAddress TS2 = {0x28, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x4F, 0x68, 0x14, 0x02, 0xDD};  // for DS18b20's
DeviceAddress TS3 = {0x28, 0xFF, 0x3D, 0x5C, 0x68, 0x14, 0x03, 0x5F};
DeviceAddress TS4 = {0x28, 0xFF, 0x16, 0x5C, 0x68, 0x14, 0x03, 0xD7};
DeviceAddress TS5 = {0x28, 0xFF, 0xA3, 0x62, 0x51, 0x14, 0x04, 0xC4};
DeviceAddress TS6 = {0x28, 0xFF, 0xA9, 0x61, 0x68, 0x14, 0x03, 0x22};
DeviceAddress TS7 = {0x28, 0xFF, 0x2A, 0x72, 0x68, 0x14, 0x03, 0x17};
DeviceAddress TS8 = {0x28, 0xFF, 0xD2, 0x61, 0x68, 0x14, 0x03, 0x3F};
DeviceAddress TS9 = {0x28, 0xFF, 0xFA, 0x43, 0x68, 0x14, 0x02, 0xD0};
DeviceAddress TS10 = {0x28, 0xFF, 0x0B, 0x63, 0x68, 0x14, 0x02, 0xCB};
DeviceAddress TS11 = {0x28, 0xFF, 0x97, 0x41, 0x68, 0x14, 0x02, 0x2A};
DeviceAddress TS12 = {0x28, 0xFF, 0x47, 0x7E, 0x68, 0x14, 0x03, 0xF8};

DeviceAddress TS16 = {0x28, 0xC8, 0x47, 0x15, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF0};

float t1;
float t2;
float t3;
float t4;
float t5;
float t6;
float t7;
float t8;
float t9;
float t10;
float t11;
float t12;
float t13;

String command = "";
boolean stringComplete = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  sensors.begin();

  pinMode(temppin, INPUT);

  // Initialize wifi shield
  if (!cc3000.begin()) {
    Serial.println(F("\n\nFailed to initialize WiFi shield."));
  }
  Serial.println(F("\n\nInitialized WiFi shield"));

  // Connect to wifi network
  if (!cc3000.connectToAP(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS, WLAN_SECURITY)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to connect to WiFi network"));
  }
  Serial.print(F("Connected to "));
  Serial.println(F(WLAN_SSID));

  // Wait for DHCP to complete (get an IP address)
  while (!cc3000.checkDHCP()) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println(F("Waiting to get IP address"));
  }
  Serial.println(F("Got an IP address\n"));

  // Connect to dweet.io
  while (dweetioIp == 0) {
    if (! cc3000.getHostByName("dweet.io", &dweetioIp)) {
      Serial.println(F("Failed to resolve dweetio website"));
    }
    delay(500);
    Serial.println(F("Resolving dweetio website"));
  }
  Serial.print("Accessed dweetio website at IP address: ");
  cc3000.printIPdotsRev(dweetioIp);  
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  // Get temperatures
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  delay(1000);
  t1 = sensors.getTempC(TS1);
  t2 = sensors.getTempC(TS2);
  t3 = sensors.getTempC(TS3);
  t4 = sensors.getTempC(TS4);
  t5 = sensors.getTempC(TS5);
  t6 = sensors.getTempC(TS6);
  t7 = sensors.getTempC(TS7);
  t8 = sensors.getTempC(TS8);
  t9 = sensors.getTempC(TS9);
  t10 = sensors.getTempC(TS10);
  t11 = sensors.getTempC(TS11);
  t12 = sensors.getTempC(TS12);
  t13 = sensors.getTempC(TS16);   

  Serial.println(t1);
  Serial.println(t2);
  Serial.println(t3);
  Serial.println(t4);
  Serial.println(t5);
  Serial.println(t6);
  Serial.println(t7);
  Serial.println(t8);
  Serial.println(t9);
  Serial.println(t10);
  Serial.println(t11);
  Serial.println(t12);
  Serial.println(t13);

  long curmillis = millis();
  if (curmillis - lastpost > 1000*15L) {
    // Post data to dweetio
    char data[125];
    sprintf(data, "?t1=%i&t2=%i&t3=%i&t4=%i&t5=%i&t6=%i&t7=%i&t8=%i&t9=%i&t10=%i&t11=%i&t12=%i&t13=%i", 
            (int)(t1*10.),(int)(t2*10.),(int)(t3*10.),(int)(t4*10.),(int)(t5*10.),
            (int)(t6*10.),(int)(t7*10.),(int)(t8*10.),(int)(t9*10.),(int)(t10*10.),
            (int)(t11*10.),(int)(t12*10.),(int)(t13*10.));
    Adafruit_CC3000_Client client = cc3000.connectTCP(dweetioIp, 80);
    if (client.connected()) {
      client.fastrprint(F("GET "));
      client.fastrprint(F("/dweet/for/testdweets"));
      client.fastrprint(data);
      client.fastrprint(F(" HTTP/1.1\r\n"));
      client.fastrprint(F("Host: https://www.dweet.io\r\n"));
      client.fastrprint(F("\r\n\r\n"));
      // client.println();
      Serial.println(F("Sent dweet\n"));
    } else {
      Serial.println(F("Sending dweet failed"));
      return;
    }

    /* Read data until either the connection is closed, or the idle timeout is reached. */ 
    unsigned long lastRead = millis();
    while (client.connected() && (millis() - lastRead < 1000)) {
      while (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        Serial.print(c);
        lastRead = millis();
      }
    }

    client.close();
    Serial.println("Connection to dweet.io closed");

    lastpost = millis();
  }
}
```